# How to use Android flavors to make a build for detox testing with higher minSdkVersion - - React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, detox, android-flavors

I want to use Detox for React-native e2e testing which requires minSdkVersion of 18, but my app is on 16. I'm not yet ready to upgrade to 18 for my app, so i want to use android flavors to make one build for detox testing and another for production.
here is what i've done so far :
in app/build.gradle :

```
flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        detox {
            // Assigns this product flavor to the "version" flavor dimension.
            // If you are using only one dimension, this property is optional,
            // and the plugin automatically assigns all the module's flavors to
            // that dimension.
            dimension "version"
            versionNameSuffix "-detox"
            minSdkVersion 18
        }
        prod {
            dimension "version"
            versionNameSuffix "-prod"
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
    }
```

Now in android studio i have 4 build variants : detoxDebug is synchronising ok but productionDebug gives this error:

[image]

**THANKS!**